# Server Error in ASPNet Application, error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm new in Asp.Net Web Forms, I'm making my first app but I have this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)

Someone know what is wrong?

Comment: If you want to get some answers  you should show your code.
It's your's first WEB application but is this your first application with database connection ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check database connection string to ensure that the server host, database name and credentials are correct.

Comment: I think that the problem is right there, when I change the Data Source in the <connectionStrings>  i have a new error:
         Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.